# how can I get rid off duplicate defect(accuwork) on AccuRev

Tags: accurev

I am seeing there are duplicate issues with one defect within a minute. why this is happening and how can i get rid off this? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to delete/remove an issue from AccuWork.  You will need to close the duplicate issues that have been created and just keep the original open.

As for why this is happening, you could look at the history of these issues and see who is creating them.  I am going to guess you have an automated process or an AccuBridge solution in place which creates the issues.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. yes you are right we can close the duplicate one. But the problem is, it was not happening one time or so. we had multiple times.
AccuBridge is place which was working fine. But we kinda solved by ending the AccuBridge process. still trying to dig.

Comment: Which AccuBridge are you using and on what OS is the bridge running?  I have seen instances where multiple issues would appear if you had multiple instances of the bridge running.

Comment: ClearQuest and windows. what you meant by multiple instances?

Comment: By multiple instances = two bridges running simultaneously.  Are you running the AccuBridge as a service?

Answer (score 1):

Check for more than one perl process on the machine running accubridge. That would be an indicator that you have multiple instances of the bridge running.